# What tense is this rhetorical question?

Tags: tenses, would

I'm having trouble figuring out the tense of this sentence:

> What heart wouldn’t fill with awe upon hearing the events of her birth?

Comment: Which tense do you think it is?

Comment: At first I thought it was past tense, but it seems like it might depend on the context it's mentioned in?

Comment: 'Would' is a modal and is used in constructions with [other] verbs. 'Hearing' is a participle - a present participle, but that doesn't mean it is present tense.

Comment: Even with a context in the past, this question is not past or present: "They were so happy when she was born." But "Who wouldn't be happy?" does not refer to the past.

Comment: The tense of a tensed clause is marked on the first auxiliary verb (or on the main verb, if there are no auxiliaries). The first auxiliary verb in this sentence is a modal auxiliary verb, which do not inflect for tense, and therefore the tense of this sentence is indeterminate. The simplest solution is to say there's no tense. Another is to pick a tense, present or past, arbitrarily. Since it doesn't matter what tense it is, either one will do for labelling purposes if your professor demands you label it. Nobody else will ever care.

Answer (score 0):

It is **past tense,** using the terminology of Huddleston & Pullum (2002). "Would" is the past tense form of the auxiliary "will." The past tense is here conveying not past time but *modal remoteness,* in this case the improbability of someone's heart not filling with awe.

Comment: Calling *would* the past tense of *will* is one of more specious things CGEL does; modal auxiliary verbs have no tense or person.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I do think that they have a point here; this account helps explain backshifting of reported speech and the use of "would" in counterfactual conditionals. But I'll make it clear in my answer that I'm using H&P's terminology.

Comment: Though nobody but a syntax teacher would ever care which terminology one uses, especially when they're not useful.

Comment: @JohnLawler Fair enough. One of these days I'll get around to reading McCawley's *The Syntactic Phenomena of English* so that I can have *two* sets of terminology to annoy people with.

Comment: @alphabet The main difference is that CGEL concentrates on terminology and delimiting categorizations -- everything in its proper box in the grid -- whereas McCawley is far more concerned with establishing connections and relations between syntactic phenomena instead of labelling them. He only makes distinctions he can argue for rather than establishing them by definition and fiat. I find his examples and analyses much more reasonable.

Comment: @JohnLawler Ok! I'm trying to avoid becoming "a man of one book."